# get value from activity using Interface in Android

Tags: android, methods, interface

I have a Activity Class with method doLogin() like this :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public void doLogin(final String email, String url) {
    asyncThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String username = email;
            //.......
  }
}
```

i will use the interface with my custom SDK, so other app. can send value "email" and "url" to LoginActivity.doLogin() using interface/callback, please give me an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways: event buses, through global objects (application class), through retained fragment,..

But the standard way is to use Intents.

In the LoginActivity:

```
String mymail = "email";
String myurl = "some/url";
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.MAIL_KEY, mymail);
intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.URL_KEY, myurl);
startActivity(intent);
```

Extract data in the OtherActivity:

```
...
public static final String MAIL_KEY = "my.app.package.mail_key";
public static final String URL_KEY = "my.app.package.url_key";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String mymail = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MAIL_KEY);
    String myurl = getIntent().getExtras().getString(URL_KEY);
```

Comment: would you like to give me an example using intent please?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do it via an interface between 2 activities.  You'd send them as parameters in the intent used to start the activity.  Or if the other activity started you you'd return them as extras in the result intent.  You never use an interface to talk between activities.

Comment: i will use this interface with my custom SDK, so other app. can using my doLogin() method with just callback email parameter

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You can't get access to a reference of another actvity without doing ugly hacks that you shouldn't ever do.  The only proper way to talk to another activity is via Intent.  Now you can create a factory method to make creating the intent easy and hide the details if you prefer.

Comment: is there other way without using intent? i want to pass parameter from other class (activity/fragment/etc) to my class (activity/fragment/etc)